# Don't update a comment converted from an answer when the deleted answer is edited

Tags: feature-request, answers, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

I converted an answer to a comment because it was just a question for the OP. The [original answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/5813c92d-2c25-4251-845b-4ed5104fbd4c/view-source) was the following:

> What happens if you would use a page callback like '`drupal_get_form`' instead of '`question_mark_page`' ?

After the conversion, the author of the (now deleted) answer, edited it, [changing it as follows](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/bf812280-2a97-49b1-b1a6-adb1ff46f491/view-source).

> Try changing the page callback from '`question_mark_page`' to '`drupal_get_form`' ...
>
> It is also what is suggested in multiple answers in the question to [How to add module to admin/config page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1757) ...
>
> Note: I believe this question is NOT a duplicate of that question ...

The same happened to the [converted comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159476/why-does-my-admin-menu-link-for-my-custom-module-not-get-created/159480#comment192497_159476) too.

The converted comment should not be changed when the answer is edited.

I [reverted back the edit done to the answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/6d51fce2-9148-4ce5-b3e8-b9ee7a1cd7a7/view-source), but that is not reflected on the comment.
I verified that the comment was not edited after being converted, and there is not the usual icon that shows the comment was edited after being created.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but the links don't seem to work properly? I'm getting 404s for all of them other than the one in the quote box.

Comment: They work for me. The answer is deleted, if this makes any difference. Plus, I am a moderator on Drupal Answers.

Comment: Being able to view deleted answers is something you have to have sufficient rep for, so that's probably the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do not and have never done this.

Timeline of events:

- You converted the answer to a comment.
- They edited the answer in disagreement.
- They deleted the original comment that was created from the conversion.
- They posted a new comment with the edited content from the answer, which has a timestamp several minutes after the edit occurred.